# PHP / Javascript / JQuery - base64 sha256 encoding

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sha256, hmac

I'm trying to port a PHP example of an API integration to Javascript / JQuery. In PHP, an encrypted string is created using the following code:

```
$sig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $sign, $this->secretAccessKey, true)
```

whose functions are documented here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php

http://us.php.net/base64_encode

In Javascript, I'm using JQuery's crypto to do the HMAC piece:

```
http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#HMAC-SHA256
```

and I'm trying to figure out if I also need to do a base64 encode, as it seems it is already in base64. This is the code I'm currently running:

```
var sigHash = Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, sign, accessKey);
```

Is this correct? How would I create a javascript / jquery equivalent of the above PHP function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HMAC is a standard. So is SHA-256. So their outputs, regardless of which implementation, **has to be** the same.

There could only be differences in the Base64 encoding. Normally, the non-alphanumeric characters are `+` and `/`, but you cannot count on that. I've checked, and both implementations use the same non-alphanumeric characters.

However, you should still "manually" check a few thousand strings. The implementation in PHP is well tested. But I do not know if the same is true for the implementation in jQuery...

The syntax for Base64 encoded output is:

```
Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(
    Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, sign, accessKey, { asBytes: true })
);
```

Comment: Thanks - I think what I need to know though, is it enough just to run the crypto function in javascript to get the equivalent to the PHP functions, or do I need to run the crypto function, and an addition base64_encode function

Comment: The standard output of the function is hexadecimal encoding, not Base64. For Base64 encoding, see updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need inspiration for a JS implementation of a PHP function, have a look at PHPJS.org. The JavaScript equivalent for `base64_encode` can be found at: [base64_encode](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode:358).