# Encryption in nodejs

Tags: php, javascript, node.js, base64, sha256

I'm trying to port the following php code to javascript on node.js:

`$mac = hash_hmac('SHA256', 'string', 'secret', true);

$coded = base64_encode($mac);`

I've tried the following:

`var Crypto = require('crypto');

var code = Crypto.util.bytesToBase64(Crypto.HMAC(Crypto.SHA256, 'string', 'secret', { asBytes: true }));`

I get the error:

> TypeError: Object #Object has no method 'HMAC'

I'm new to node.js, what am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

> var code = Crypto.createHmac('SHA256', secret_key).update(to_encode).digest('base64');

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use the `createHmac` function instead.

```
Crypto.createHmac("SHA256", 'secret').update('string').digest('base64')
```

Comment: Thanks. I get "Must give hashtype string as argument".

Comment: @Alex Sorry, the docs aren't that great, so I couldn't figure out what exactly it wanted. Hopefully this gets you in the right direction.

Comment: Crypto.SHA256 should be 'SHA256'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The method is called [`createHmac`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/crypto.html#crypto.createHmac)

```
> Crypto = require('crypto');
{ Credentials: [Function: Credentials],
  createCredentials: [Function],
  Hash: [Function],
  createHash: [Function],
  Hmac: [Function],
  createHmac: [Function],
  Cipher: [Function],
  createCipher: [Function],
  createCipheriv: [Function],
  Decipher: [Function],
  createDecipher: [Function],
  createDecipheriv: [Function],
  Sign: [Function],
  createSign: [Function],
  Verify: [Function],
  createVerify: [Function],
  DiffieHellman: [Function],
  createDiffieHellman: [Function],
  pbkdf2: [Function],
  randomBytes: [Function],
  pseudoRandomBytes: [Function],
  rng: [Function],
  prng: [Function] }
```

Comment: I took it from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909288/php-javascript-jquery-base64-sha256-encoding

Comment: @Alex It is probably for an older version of node